# unauthorized access to my spring application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, rest, jwt

im working on a spring boot +angular+mysql e-commerce web application
the database is working fine and i can send requests using postman[image: the status say 403 forbidden]
and i have access to the database[image: the line was added] and i can alter it through requests
but when i try to open the localhost[image: error image] it says that i dont have authority to access it
im using JWT and spring security for this app

i havent tried anything since i dont fully understand the security part so i didnt want to end up ruining it i kept following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUll19GMQn4&list=PLvJa0Vs1x3dUkiNMuLI7UUGqCL3F4UDIY&index=3&ab_channel=CodeElevate)

Comment: It can be an issue from spring security, try checking the configuration, disable csrf

Comment: @NgoTuoc 'disable basic security feature' is incredibly horrible advice.

Comment: @rzwitserloot csrf not security! Please read the docs

Comment: https://spring.io/projects/spring-security#learn

Comment: csrf is a way to compromise a server. Disabling it without knowing what it is or does is incredibly horrible advice. Your provided link isn't about csrf nor links to a section that explains how, somehow, just 'disable csrf' without knowing what it does has zero impact on security, name notwithstanding.

Comment: Have you been adding authorization header in your request header when you send your request by postman??? if you use jwt tokens you must add this token that is given from login api to your authorization header